# Finding score of first test taken

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have students that have taken a test multiple times.  I want to return the first test they took along with that score.

I have tried this which does not work it returns all dates, when I remove `scaledscore` it returns min date and correct student id.

What am I missing?

```
SELECT StudentLocalID, MIN(AssessmentDate),scaledscore fROM dbo.Ren_sel
GROUP BY StudentLocalID,AssessmentDate,scaledscore
ORDER BY StudentLocalID
```

my data looks like

```
1   02/01/2014 630
1   02/25/2014 741
2   04/01/2014 894
2   03/15/2014 759
```

needed results

```
1   02/01/2014 630
2   03/15/2014 759
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT StudentLocalID, AssessmentDate,scaledscore 
 FROM (
       SELECT StudentLocalID, AssessmentDate,scaledscore 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentLocalID ORDER BY AssessmentDate ASC) rn                      
        fROM dbo.Ren_sel
      )A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT StudentLocalID, AssessmentDate, ScaledScore 
FROM Ren_sel r
WHERE AssessmentDate = 
(
    SELECT MIN(AssessmentDate) FROM Ren_sel
    WHERE StudentLocalID = r.StudentLocalID 
    GROUP BY StudentLocalID
)
```

Or you could use a derived table:

```
SELECT r.StudentLocalID, AssessmentDate, ScaledScore FROM Ren_sel r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT StudentLocalID, MIN(AssessmentDate) mindate FROM Ren_sel
    GROUP BY StudentLocalID
) a ON r.StudentLocalID = a.StudentLocalID AND r.AssessmentDate = a.mindate
```

The latter might give better performance in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use Ranking functions and Derived Table, you can use CTE (Common Table Expressions) too.

```
WITH C AS (
    SELECT StudentLocalID, MIN(AssessmentDate) AS firstTest fROM dbo.Ren_sel
    GROUP BY StudentLocalID
)
SELECT ren.StudentLocalID, C.firstTest, ren.scaledscore FROM dbo.Ren_sel AS ren
    INNER JOIN C
    ON ren.StudentLocalID = C.StudentLocalID
    WHERE ren.AssessmentDate = C.firstTest
```